# how to create method disable /enable for child entite in parent entite?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

> RefDataLigne

```
public class RefDataLigne {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
public String code;
public String description;
public String values;
public boolean enabled;
@Column(name = "table_id")
private long tableCode;}
```

> ReferentielTable

```
public class ReferentielTable {
```

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long table_id;

public String code;
public String description;

```
@OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="table_id" , referencedColumnName = "table_id")
public List<RefDataLigne> data ;
```

}

> i need to find : method disableDataLineInTable()
> if you have a tutorial because i am beginning  and thank you .
>
> for exemple : post have one or many comments i need a two methods first can enable comment and other method can disable comment.

Comment: Can you please be more exact what do you mean by "disableDataLineInTable"?

You would like to do an edit and change the value of "enabled" in child table?

Comment: for exemple : post  have one or many comments  i need a two  methods first can enable comment and other method can disable comment.

Comment: You would need to do this over your service level. 
You would get the <post> and then change the state of <comment>.

If you want to do this over Entity level then you would need to call this function before flush.

Example would be : 

 public void enableAllComments(){
        this.data.forEach(refDataLigne -> refDataLigne.setEnabled(true));
    }

Comment: thank you so much ,  this method for enable all comment , but  i want to enable just one comment in post i have to presise  id for one comment .